# How to force a variable in Ansible to be only 3 CHARS or only numbers?

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I have the following task in Ansible:

```yaml
- name: Run multiple queries
  community.general.hana_query:
    sid: "{{ sid | default('HDB') | upper }}"
    instance: "{{ instance | default('01') }}"
```

Variable `sid` must be 3 CHARS.
Variable `instance` can be any number between `01` and `99`.

How can i force it in script?

Comment: Parts of a possible answer may be find under [How can I check numeric string](https://serverfault.com/questions/951294/how-can-i-check-numeric-string).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you want the task to run only when the variable is 3 chars or only numbers and skip otherwise?
If that's the case then you can simply do the checks within a when conditional and use the `length` and `int` filters.

```yaml
- name: Run multiple queries
  community.general.hana_query:
    sid: "{{ sid | upper }}"
    instance: "{{ instance }}"
  when:
    - sid | length == 3
    - instance | int
```

Do you want the playbook to fail when the variable is neither 3 chars or only numbers?
If that's the case, then you can do a assert before the task.

```yaml
- name: Check if variables are legit
  assert:
    that:
      - sid | length == 3
      - instance | int
```

Or do you want to trim the variable so that it fits your requirements?
You can choose the first 3 characters of `sid` with `[:3]`.
And do a `regex_replace` to remove any characters that are not numbers in `instance`, and then choose the first 2 with `[:2]`.

```yaml
- name: Run multiple queries
  community.general.hana_query:
    sid: "{{ (sid | upper)[:3] }}"
    instance: "{{ (instance | regex_replace('[^0-9]+', ''))[:2] }}"
```